# What is the difference between Remix and Remix IDE

Tags: remix

What is the difference between [Remix](https://github.com/ethereum/remix) and [Remix IDE](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your first link:

> **Remix** is a suite of tools to interact with the Ethereum blockchain in order to debug transactions, stored in this Git repository. A Remix transaction Web debugger is available [here](http://remix.ethereum.org), and its source code is part of this repository.
>
> The **Remix IDE** is an IDE for Solidity dApp developers, powered by Remix. The Remix IDE repository **is available [here](https://github.com/ethereum/remix-ide)**, and an online version is available at https://remix.ethereum.org.